# ifstream: reading integer values in decimal format and in hexadecimal format from a file

Tags: c++, ifstream

Probably not the first one to ask this, but couldn't find the right answer...

I'm attempting to read integer values from a text file, using an `ifstream` object.

Some integer values are represented in decimal format, and others in hexadecimal format.

**For example:**

```
0xAB 1 2 3
4 5 0x12 6
6 0xF 1 23
```

The following code used to work (back in the VS6 days), for **both** decimal and hexadecimal strings:

```
ifstream file(fileName);
int value = 0;
file >> value;
```

After porting it to MSVC++ 2010, it appears to be working only for decimal strings.

So I'm assuming that something basic has changed in the `std::stream` classes.

Am I correct? If yes, then what is it?

In any case, how can I read all integer values from a file, without checking the format of each string?

Thanks

**Update - while porting my project from VS6 to MSVC++ 2010, I also had to change:**

From this:

```
#include <fstream.h>
```

Into this:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

Perhaps that's what made the difference, though I cannot see how...

**Another update:**

Due to the the GLUI library in my project, I have to link some of the old default libraries; the following page might shed some light: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h8eh904%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.

Comment: `<fstream.h>` is non-standard, so that might have had something to do with it.

Comment: You probably do need to handle them differently.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: So what happened since VS6.0? Where is the difference in the `ifstream` class (or anywhere else for that matter)?

Comment: [Confirmed that this does not work in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cad0b778cc623e7c). To be honest, I thought it did.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Well, it works with `ss >> std::hex >> value`, but I am still running into problems at some point when the `ifstream` object simply "stops working", and I am unable to figure out why. The link I added in my question (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h8eh904%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) may provide additional insights on this, but I'm still not sure how to handle the problem.

Comment: @barakmanos: Well when you try to extract something and the extraction fails, internal error flags are set. The stream won't do anything then until you clear those error flags. The fact that it "stops working" isn't the surprise; that you _must_ explicitly choose `std::hex` or `std::dec` to extract into an `int` is [arguably] the surprise, and certainly the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I changed my code to use `ifstream>>i` for decimal values and `ifstream>>hex>>i` for hexadecimal values (unlike the example above, in my real input file, I know exactly where the decimal values are located and where the hexadecimal values are located). But that didn't solve the problem, and I still end up with the `ifstream` object "not working". Also, in the previous version of my project (on VS6), I never had to use the `hex` object, and file-reading always completed successfully.

Comment: @barakmanos: That should have worked. Please adjust your testcase accordingly.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: What should have worked???

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: As I mention in the question - there are two problems at hand: 1. The fact that I need to use `hex` for values represented in hexadecimal format (a problem that did not exist on previous versions of the STL). 2. The fact that the `ifstream` object stops reading values from the file at a certain point **even** if I do use the `hex` object where needed. I gave the above example so that I wouldn't get answers in the form of "use `hex` once, at the beginning of every line".

Comment: Please read my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with std::hex modifier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c80c6bc00031fc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("1 2 3 0XFF 4 5 6");
    unsigned value = 0;
    while (ss >> std::hex >> value) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
255
4
5
6
```

I've just add std::hex to @lightness-races-in-orbit proposal.